# Why isn't this PHP code validating user input?

Tags: php, html

I am creating a form with a validation code. I already know the form works as I'm building off of a previous project by adding the validation code. I am doing this for a class and I followed exactly what the example showed. For whatever reason though, it isn't validating. I don't need someone to tell me how to do my homework, but I could really use a point in the right direction here.

The code below is from my HTML file which, when the form is submitted, passes the data through a PHP file. It's only the validation code in the HTML file that I'm struggling with, so I won't attach the PHP file.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="basics.css"/>
<title>Form Process</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="holder">
  <?php
  $fname=$_POST['fname'];
  $lname=$_POST['lname'];
  $street=$_POST['street'];
  $city=$_POST['city'];
  $state=$_POST['state'];
  $zip=$_POST['zip'];
  $phone=$_POST['phone'];
  if (empty($fname)) {
    $error_message="You must enter a value for your first name!";
  } else if (empty($lname)) {
    $error_message="You must enter a value for your last name!";
  } else if (empty($street)) {
    $error_message="You must enter a value for your street address!";
  } else if (empty($city)) {
    $error_message="You must enter a value for your city!";
  } else if (empty($state)) {
    $error_message="You must enter a value for your state!";
  } else if (empty($zip)) {
    $error_message="You must enter a value for your zip code!";
  } else if (empty($phone)) {
    $error_message="You must enter a value for your phone number!";
  } else {
    $error_message="You must enter a value!";
  }
?>
<h1>Sign Up Now!</h1>
<center><form action="info_output_includes.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" id="street" name="street" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>City:</td><td><input type="text" id="city" name="city" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>State:</td><td><input type="text" id="state" name="state"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Zip Code:</td><td><input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Phone:</td><td><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"/></td></tr>
<tr ><td ><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
<td class="totheleft"><input type="reset" value="Clear" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form></center>
<br>
<a href="index.php">Home</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If the validation code were working, it should say (for example) "You must enter a value for your first name!" if the user submitted the form without entering a first name value. Of course, it should basically print an error message if any value is left empty.

Comment: `<input type="submit"` has no `name value`

Comment: @dean that part of the code didn't give me trouble prior to adding the validation code being added though

Comment: Nothing is preventing it from posting directly to info_output_includes.php. The validation is server side (php), so in this case it isn't validated prior to form submission. If it must be client side validation then you can use javascript or html5. For example: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required="required"/>. This will throw an html5 required message. You will still need to validate on the server side too, to ensure it is truly validated.

Comment: @user9189147 hmm I was just going off of what my professor was showing us. I remove the validation code here & move it to the PHP file, should it work the way I'm wanting it to?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not seeing the error is because you're not outputting it somewhere. You need to add a line like:

```
<?php echo $error_message; ?>
```

Restructuring the code in a more logical way using only HTML like you have it, would be:

```
<?php
  $fname=$_POST['fname'];
  $lname=$_POST['lname'];
  $street=$_POST['street'];
  $city=$_POST['city'];
  $state=$_POST['state'];
  $zip=$_POST['zip'];
  $phone=$_POST['phone'];

  if (empty($fname)) {
    $error_message="You must enter a value for your first name!";
  } else if (empty($lname)) {
    $error_message="You must enter a value for your last name!";
  } else if (empty($street)) {
    $error_message="You must enter a value for your street address!";
  } else if (empty($city)) {
    $error_message="You must enter a value for your city!";
  } else if (empty($state)) {
    $error_message="You must enter a value for your state!";
  } else if (empty($zip)) {
    $error_message="You must enter a value for your zip code!";
  } else if (empty($phone)) {
    $error_message="You must enter a value for your phone number!";
  } else {
    $error_message="You must enter a value!";
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="lrt">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="basics.css"/>
    <title>Form Process</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="holder">
        <h1>Sign Up Now!</h1>
        <div style="color:red;"><?php echo $error_message; ?></div>
        <center>
            <form name="input-form" action="info_output_includes.php" method="post">
                <table>
                <tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" id="street" name="street" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>City:</td><td><input type="text" id="city" name="city" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>State:</td><td><input type="text" id="state" name="state"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Zip Code:</td><td><input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Phone:</td><td><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"/></td></tr>
                <tr ><td ><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                <td class="totheleft"><input type="reset" value="Clear" /></td></tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </center>
        <br>
        <a href="index.php">Home</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Where would I add a line like that though? Within the initial PHP code?

Comment: No, anywhere inside your HTML. For example, below the `<h1>Sign Up Now!</h1>`, you can add the line: `<div style="color:red;"><?php echo $error_message; ?></div>`. This should point out the error in your HTML.

Comment: I have added a code example above with your code properly indented, added a form name and the error output.